# (OG) Example function to detect User's roles?

Tags: users, organic-groups, distributions

Using Open Atrium 6.x-1.2 (Organic Groups 6.x-2.3 inc it's access control.mod), would someone be as kind to provide an example function that would detect the current user's role? It's my understanding OG overrides the standard Drupal permissions page. My end goal is to allow certain roles access to groups they don't specifically have membership (eg: Executive) for a custom OA/OG access control policy/module.

Would some implementation of Rules be possible here?

My skill level: no PHP but just started studying module dev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To test whether the currently-logged-in User has a specific Role, you can do this:

```
global $user;
if (in_array('Executive', $user->roles)) {
  drupal_set_message("I have the 'Executive' role.");
}
```

Comment: Wow. Seems I was thinking things would be more complicated by the nature of OG ignoring the standard Drupal perms. Brilliant & my thanks to you, good sir.

Comment: @TheDoctor Please don't change the title if the question becomes solved, simply mark the answer as accepted as stated in [ask]